# ajax did not work, can't load the update_loc.php

Tags: php, ajax

```
var warp1_data = {
  "id": "warp1",
  "x": 371,
  "y": 95,
  "images": 'map/town/balamb.png',
  "framerate": 32,
  "animations":
    {
      "down": [0, 3, "down", 0.25],
      "left": [4, 7, "left", 0.25],
      "right": [8, 11, "right", 0.25],
      "up": [12, 15, "up", 0.25],
      "downLeft": [16, 19, "downLeft", 0.25],
      "downRight": [20, 23, "downRight", 0.25],
      "upLeft": [24, 27, "upLeft", 0.25],
      "upRight": [28, 31, "upRight", 0.25]
    },
  "frames":
    {
      "height": 32,
      "width":32,
      "regX": 0,
      "regY": 0,
      "count": 32
    },
  "movement":
    {
      "type" : '8dir',
      "distanceOnPress" : 4,
      "keycodeUp" : -1,
      "keycodeDown" : -1,
      "keycodeLeft" : -1,
      "keycodeRight" : -1
    },
  "collisionObject": true,
  "collisionType": "pixel",
  "collisionAlphaThreshold": 10,
  "onCollision": function() {
    //only allow the collision text once every 5 seconds
    if (!window.playerCollisionTxt) {
      window.playerCollisionTxt = true;
      setTimeout(function(){ window.playerCollisionTxt = false; }, 5000);


        $.ajax({
            url: "update_loc.php",
            type: "GET",
            data: { 'username': user, 'liked': '1' },                   
            success: function()
                        {
                            alert("ok");                                    
                        }
        });

      location.reload();
    }
  }
};
```

Is there something wrong with this code?  I have added this to my HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

All I want is to connect JavaScript AJAX to SQL database.

Anyway I am using abyss web server latest version & here is my PHP file:

```
<?php

include "config.php";
$get_move_loc_1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$CONFIG['database'].".login WHERE userid='".$_SESSION['ff_account']."' LIMIT 1");
$get_move_loc_2 = mysql_fetch_array($get_move_loc_1);

$get_move_loc_3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$CONFIG['database'].".char WHERE account_id='".$get_move_loc_2['account_id']."' LIMIT 1");
$get_move_loc_4 = mysql_fetch_array($get_move_loc_3);

$char_id = $get_move_loc_4['char_id'];

mysql_query("UPDATE ".$CONFIG['database'].".char SET last_map='Balamb Garden' WHERE char_id='$char_id'");
mysql_query("UPDATE ".$CONFIG['database'].".char SET map_x='371' WHERE char_id='$char_id'");
mysql_query("UPDATE ".$CONFIG['database'].".char SET map_y='115' WHERE char_id='$char_id'");
```

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your jQuery version is from Stone Age (version 1.2 really??). Update to a recent version please.
2. Your ajax request is fine. No problem with that if `update_loc.php` is reached.
3. But just after the ajax call you've got `location.reload();` that reloads the page. I think is this that is confusing you. Remove it and it's all.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i already figure it out,, i forgot to add the session start in php.